# What can primes, except 2, 3, and 5, be congruent to $\pmod {30}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

After some trials, I found out that a prime $p \gt 5$ is congruent to $q\pmod{30}$, where $q$ is also a prime, and $1 \le q \lt 30 \;$ (i.e.  $p \equiv q\pmod{30}.$

Is there a way to write a formal proof to show this?  Is that an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens to be true for a $30$ (if you allow $q=1$ as gnometorule pointed out), but not necessarily for other moduli.

For example, $109 \equiv 49 \pmod{60}$, but $109$ is prime and $49$ isn't.

In general the possible remainders of primes are everything (in the appropriate range) that is coprime with the modulus, by [Dirichlet's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions). When the modulus is 30, it just happens that all of these, except 1, are primes themselves.

Comment: Also, 30 is the _last_ number with the property that all numbers less than it and coprime to it are prime - beyond 30 the so-called _primorials_ grow too quickly for this property to hold; see http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/9247.html for a proof.

Answer (score 3):

As gnometorule points out this isn't true because $1$ is not a prime.  It is on the other hand true that every prime is congruent to $1 \leq q < 30$, modulo $30$, where $q$ is either $1$ or a prime.

The reason is because every number between $1$ and $29$ which is not prime is divisible by at least one of $2, 3, 5$.  As $30$ is also divisible by these numbers this means any number congruent to these is divisible by one of $2, 3, 5$.

Answer (score 2):

31 isn't. (adding minimum # chars)

Comment: Right, since $1$ is a unit and that $31 \equiv 1 \pmod{30}$.  I think the same would go for $61$.  So $p$ would be congruent to either $1$ or a prime that is less than $30$.